# Outlook Room Finder not working with Address Book Policy

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013, exchange

Background :

I have a multi tenant exchange 2013 environment that is built by segmenting each tenant with the use of Address Book Policies (ABP).
This is working very well as each tenant can only see their organisation's users, groups, rooms and contacts - as intended.

The thing that isn't working is the room finder feature that is built into outlook 2010/13.

The room finder is populated by special distribution groups that have the -roomlist parameter checked. Members (room mailboxes) of that distribution group are displayed in the roomfinder pane in outlook.

Let me explain a bit more:

If User A is not in an ABP, the room finder shows all roomlists in the room finder (distribution groups with the -roomlist attribute) within the whole environment.

If User A is in an ABP then they cannot see any rooms/room lists in the room finder **but can see them in the address book and when they press the rooms button when setting up a meeting.** (i.e. the address book policies are working as intended)

The cmdlets used to create each tenant are: New-GlobalAddressList

> New-GlobalAddressList -Name "TenantName - GAL" -ConditionalCustomAttribute15 "ABC" -IncludedRecipients MailboxUsers -RecipientContainer "Path/to/OU
>
> New-AddressList -Name "TenantName - All Rooms" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute15 -eq 'ABC') -and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox')" -RecipientContainer "Path/to/OU
>
> New-AddressList -Name "TenantName - All Users" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute15 -eq 'ABC') -and
>   (ObjectClass -eq 'User')" -RecipientContainer "Path/to/OU
>
> New-AddressList -Name "TenantName - All Contacts" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute15 -eq 'ABC) -and (ObjectClass -eq 'Contact')" -RecipientContainer "Path/to/OU
>
> New-AddressList -Name "TenantName - All Groups" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute15 -eq 'ABC') -and
>   (ObjectClass -eq 'Group')" -RecipientContainer "Path/to/OU
>
> New-OfflineAddressBook -Name "TenantName" -AddressLists "TenantName - GAL"
>
> New-AddressBookPolicy -Name "TenantName" -AddressLists "TenantName - All Users", "TenantName - All Contacts", "TenantName - All Groups" -GlobalAddressList "TenantName - GAL" -OfflineAddressBook "TenantName" -RoomList "TenantName - All Rooms"

I have tried setting the CustomAttribute15 to the same as the tenants code used in the example (ABC) thinking that the ABP would match the following condition:

New-AddressList -Name "TenantName - All Groups" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute15 -eq 'ABC') -and
(ObjectClass -eq 'Group')" -RecipientContainer "Path/to/OU

Comment: I did see you post the same on MS forums, would you mind sharing a solution for this in case you get one?
Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, of course!